# Convention for locally compact groups?

Tags: locally-compact-groups

$\bf{\text{Suppose I find the phrase:}}$

Let $G$ is a locally compact group, and $\mathcal{U}$ a basis of neighborhoods of $1$.

---

$\bf{\text{Question:}}$

Is it a convention to automatically take each $U\in\mathcal{U}$ to be compact?

---

Clearly this can be done if the need arises by the locally compact assumption on $G$, but when reading material, should this be my first interpretation such a statement?

Comment: I'd think one would specify what sort of neighborhoods are in the basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't think so, unless it is explicitly stated as a convention in what you are reading.  (Usually, an author would explicitly signal that $U$ is a compact neighbourhood if this is what was meant.)